# Import bootstrap css in createGlobalStyles?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm building a react component library with styled components. I have a `<GlobalStyles />` component for projects consuming the library. In the SASS that I'm migrating from, I had a root `index.scss` file, within which I was doing:

```css
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

I gather I cannot just put this in my global styles:

```js
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components"
const GlobalStyles = createGlobalStyle`
  @import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
`
```

How can I make sure that any project including `<GlobalStyles />` will also receive the bootstrap stylesheets?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot import the bootstrap scss stylesheet without processing it for obvious reasons.

But you can import the bootstrap stylesheet. Unfortunately `createGlobalStyle` does not handle these imports as the underlying CSSDOM imports do not handle this well. The easiest implementation would be to import the bootstrap CSS files into your library like:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

But note that this will generate an extra CSS file that users of your library will have to include with something similiar to this too.

If you would want to create this dynamically, you could try adding this from a CDN.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const head = document.head;
    const link = document.createElement('link');
    link.href = `https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css`;
    link.rel = `stylesheet`;
    head.append(link);
  }, []);
}
```

But consider the fact that these will have to be include on all components, but should not be included more than once. One way you can do this is by adding an ID to the `link` tag and querying the DOM before adding a new one.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. But what I'm asking is how to include the bootstrap styles as part of the global styles. I know I can just load a css file elsewhere, but that's not what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: @Abby as the answer specifies you can't do that yet. you will see a warning when you try to include a css file